# MySQL Opimization of insert sequences

Tags: c++, mysql, optimization, insert, mariadb

I have a realtime application that processes information and log's it to a MySQL database (actually MariaDB, a fork of MySQL).  It does anywhere around 1.5 million inserts a day + 150,000 deletes.

I am having great problems with performance and don't know how to make it function any better.

The basic structure of the application is that I have a producer class, that pushes a Struct to a threadsafe deque.  The following code

```
#include "dbUserQueue.h"


dbUserQueue::~dbUserQueue() {
}

void dbUserQueue::createConnection()
{
    sql::Driver * driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
    std::auto_ptr< sql::Connection > newCon(driver->connect(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass));
    con = newCon;
    std::auto_ptr< sql::Statement > stmt(con->createStatement());
    stmt->execute("USE twitter");
}

inline void dbUserQueue::updateStatement(const std::string & value, 
                   std::auto_ptr< sql::PreparedStatement> & stmt, const int index)
{
    if(value != "\0") stmt->setString(index, value);
    else stmt->setNull(index,sql::DataType::VARCHAR);
}

inline void dbUserQueue::updateStatement(const boost::int64_t & value, 
                   std::auto_ptr< sql::PreparedStatement> & stmt, const int index)
{
    if(value != -1) stmt->setInt64(index,value);
    else stmt->setNull(index,sql::DataType::BIGINT);
}

inline void dbUserQueue::updateStatement(const bool value, 
                   std::auto_ptr< sql::PreparedStatement> & stmt, const int index)
{
    stmt->setBoolean(index, value);
}

inline void dbUserQueue::updateStatement(const int value, 
                   std::auto_ptr< sql::PreparedStatement> & stmt, const int index)
{
    if(value != -1) stmt->setInt(index,value);
    else stmt->setNull(index,sql::DataType::INTEGER);
}

inline void dbUserQueue::updateStatementDateTime(const std::string & value, 
                   std::auto_ptr< sql::PreparedStatement> & stmt, const int & index)
{
    if(value != "\0") stmt->setDateTime(index, value);
    else stmt->setNull(index,sql::DataType::DATE);
}

/*
 * This method creates a database connection 
 * and then creates a new thread to process the incoming queue
 */
void dbUserQueue::start() {
    createConnection();
    if(con->isClosed() == false)
    {
        insertStmt = std::auto_ptr< sql::PreparedStatement>(con->prepareStatement("\
insert ignore into users(contributors_enabled, created_at, \
description, favourites_count, followers_count, \
following, friends_count, geo_enabled, id, lang, listed_count, location, \
name, notifications, screen_name, show_all_inline_media, statuses_count, \
url, utc_offset, verified) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"));
    }
    thread = boost::thread(&dbUserQueue::processLoop, this);
}

/*
 * Stops the thread once it is finished processing the information
 */
void dbUserQueue::join(){
    thread.interrupt();
    thread.join();
}

/*
 * The worker function of the thread.  
 * Pops items from the queue and updates the database accordingly.
 */
void dbUserQueue::processLoop() {
    user input;
    int recordCount = 0;
    con->setAutoCommit(false);
    while (true) {
        try {
            if(recordCount >= 1000)
            {
                recordCount = 0;
                con->commit();
            }
            // Insert all the data into the prepared statement
            if (userQ.wait_and_pop(input)) {
                updateStatement(input.contributors_enabled, insertStmt, 1);
                updateStatementDateTime(input.created_at, insertStmt, 2);
                updateStatement(input.description, insertStmt, 3);
                updateStatement(input.favourites_count, insertStmt, 4);
                updateStatement(input.followers_count, insertStmt, 5);
                updateStatement(input.following, insertStmt, 6);
                updateStatement(input.friends_count, insertStmt, 7);
                updateStatement(input.geo_enabled, insertStmt, 8);
                updateStatement(input.id, insertStmt, 9);
                updateStatement(input.lang, insertStmt, 10);
                updateStatement(input.listed_count, insertStmt, 11);
                updateStatement(input.location, insertStmt, 12);
                updateStatement(input.name, insertStmt, 13);
                updateStatement(input.notifications, insertStmt, 14);
                updateStatement(input.screenName, insertStmt, 15);
                updateStatement(input.show_all_inline_media, insertStmt, 16);
                updateStatement(input.statuses_count, insertStmt, 17);
                updateStatement(input.url, insertStmt, 18);
                updateStatement(input.utc_offset, insertStmt, 19);
                updateStatement(input.verified, insertStmt, 20);

                insertStmt->executeUpdate();
                insertStmt->clearParameters();
                recordCount++;
                continue;
            }

        } catch (std::exception & e) {
        }
    }// end of while

    // Close the statements and the connection before exiting
    insertStmt->close();
    con->commit();
    if(con->isClosed() == false)
        con->close();
}
```

My questions is on how to improve the performance?  Things I have tried:
Having multiple consumers connecting to one MySQL/MariaDB
Committing after a large number of records

```
Single Producer, Single consumer, commit after 1000 records = ~275 Seconds
Dual Producer, Triple consumers, commit after 1000 records = ~100 Seconds
Dual Producer, Triple consumers, commit after 2000 records = ~100 Seconds
Dual Producer, Triple consumers, commit every 1 record = ~100 Seconds
Dual Producer, 6 Consumers, commit every 1 record = ~95 Seconds
Dual Producer, 6 Consumers, commit every 2000 records = ~100 Seconds
Triple Producer, 6 Consumesr, commit every 2000 records = ~100 Seconds
```

A couple notes on the problem domain.  The messages to insert and or delete come randomly throughout the day with an average of ~20 inserts/deletes per second, bursts much higher but there is no reason that the updates can't be queued for a short period, as long as the queue doesn't grow to large.

The table that the data is currently being inserted into has approximately 52 million records in it.  Here is the MySQL table information

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `contributors_enabled` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `favourites_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `followers_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `following` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friends_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `geo_enabled` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `lang` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `listed_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notifications` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `show_all_inline_media` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `statuses_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `utc_offset` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MARIA DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CHECKSUM=1 PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 TRANSACTIONAL=1
```

Comment: I think you posted the wrong table structure.  You posted `tweets` but you're INSERTing to `users`.

Comment: @Larry: Thanks for the catch.  I have the problem with both parts, inserting tweets and inserting users.  I just posted one as the code is very similar.

Comment: Well, right away you have the same column indexed twice.  PRIMARY KEY (id) will produce a UNIQUE INDEX on (id).

Comment: Thanks Larry, that boosted performance about 30-40%.  I used a mysql gui to make the table and you had to check boxes next to each field, and I clicked primary key and unique, so that explains how I got both of those.  Careless mistake none the less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the code to do bulk inserts, rather than insert one row at a time.

Comment: How do you suggest doing this? Listing multiple values in the insert statement.  Would you have a prepared statement that inserted 100 records at once or would you build the SQL string on the fly and just execute it every 100 records? (I just chose 100 randomly, it could be any number). I have tried using transactions and a prepared statement, so with my [limited] understanding that should help mitigate some of those issues, because it doesn't actually update the database until I commit, making it only 1 write, and with prepared statement I reduce bandwidth by just passing the variables.

Comment: I've not done it with prepared statements, but by generating an insert statement as a string and passing the string to mysqlpp::Query. I expect you can use a prepared statement to do bulk inserts in a similar way. If you do an insert statement for each row, I think there's a lot more traffic between the client and the server, which must slow things down.

Comment: So you are suggesting a prepared statement with a set number of "values" fields.  Something like this: PrepareStatement("INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)");, and assigning the values for multiple records to the one statement and then executing it.  I see this as being very 'clunky' and feel it isn't the optimum solution. I will try it out and see if it increases performance and get back to you though.  It would be nice if there was a way to automate the insertion of multiple records.

Comment: I tried this and it has increased throughput dramatically.  Thanks.